# Why is GSL_SUCCESS and GSL_CONTINUE missing from my cygwin GSL installation?

Tags: c, gsl, scientific-computing

I am creating a simple application involving a basic one dimensional minimisation using GSL. I try to run the following, after including `gsl_min.h`

```
do
    {
      iter++;
      status = gsl_min_fminimizer_iterate (s);

      status = gsl_min_test_interval (a, b, 0.001, 0.0);

      if (status == GSL_SUCCESS)
        printf ("Converged:\n");
    }
    while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < max_iter);
```

However I get an error saying that both GSL_SUCCESS and GSL_CONTINUE are undeclared. Why could this be?

My cygwin installed libraries are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I just needed to include:

```
<gsl/gsl_errno.h>
```

Then it worked with no problems!